# Trying to deploy SSL Cert to Azure - Webrole stuck in "Waiting for role to start"

Tags: azure, umbraco

I have an Umbraco instance deployed on Azure via the Umbraco accelerator (created by smarx and Paul Sterling).

http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com

I am trying to install an SSL Certificate on Azure and am following these steps: http://sondreb.com/blog/post/windows-azure-secure-site-with-ssl-certificate.aspx.

I have deployed my certificate to my hosted service, that looks fine.  I've also added HttpsIn with 443 as the public and private port with my certificate selected.

I then right click on my project and select package, this gives me a dialog and I choose Service Configuration: Default and Build Configuration: Release.  This gives me a .cscfg file and a .cspkg file.

I then create a new staging deployment with these files through the azure silverlight interface.

The roles never spin up.  They just cycle through waiting for roll to start and initializing roll.

Does anyone know how to debug this or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave the private port in the Azure configuration blank -- the load balancer will complete this on your behalf. Like so:

[image]

It's really hard to diagnose issues with the load balancer configuration, I do wish we'd see better messages!